# SQL Server all Errors List?

Tags: sql-server-2008, error-handling

I am trying to capture a list of all SQL Server errors so my calling C# (.NET 4.0) can do different things based on what occurs.

I am trying to get all of the things in
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645611.aspx
and all of the other related pages.

Obviously SQL Server has these in a table somewhere already, but where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT message_id, severity, text
  FROM sys.messages 
  WHERE language_id = 1033; -- assuming US English
```